# Adding a column with a Default value?

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, column-defaults

I am adding a column to my database table. It is a simple Char column with either a value of 'Y' or 'N'.

Is it possible to default the column to be 'N'? If so, how?

Current Script to add column:

```
ALTER TABLE PERSON
ADD IS_ACTIVE VARCHAR2(1);
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE PERSON
ADD IS_ACTIVE VARCHAR2(1) DEFAULT 'N'
```

If you want, you can add a NOT NULL constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE PERSON
ADD IS_ACTIVE VARCHAR2(1) DEFAULT 'N' NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm):

```
ALTER TABLE person ADD is_active VARCHAR2(1) DEFAULT 'N';
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add `Default <your default value>` to it.

for example:

```
ALTER TABLE person ADD is_active VARCHAR2(20) DEFAULT 'N';
```

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE PERSON
ADD IS_ACTIVE VARCHAR(1) DEFAULT('N') NOT NULL

Answer (score 0):

MySql version

While creating table

```
CREATE TABLE tblPERSON ( id INT NOT NULL , IS_ACTIVE CHAR NULL DEFAULT 'N' )
```

Altering

```
ALTER TABLE tblperson ADD IS_ACTIVE CHAR NULL DEFAULT 'N'
```

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE PERSON ADD IS_ACTIVE CHAR(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 'N';

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name varchar2(1) DEFAULT 'N' not null;
```